# How is Android's String UsbDevice.getVersion() encoded from Word bcdDevice?

Tags: android, usb, hardware, libusb

I'm having USB device with [bcdDevice](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/structlibusb__device__descriptor.html#afb5e0fc6f0cfe51de900d35506fb9317) = 262 (word). In Android according `UsbDevice.getVersion()` shows "1.16" (String) as it's [String](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html#getVersion()). Usually the first byte is device **major** version and the second is **minor** version, which should be "1" and "6" accordingly:

```
devInfo->version.major = (dev_desc->bcdDevice >> 8) & 0xFF;
devInfo->version.minor = dev_desc->bcdDevice & 0xFF;
```

How does Android encode `String` device version from `word` bcdDevice? I need to do opposite - get "bcdDevice" value using Android "version".

Obviously "1.16" can't be parsed the following way:
"major version before "." as int, and the rest is minor version" as minor version will be 16, but it's 6 actually.

**Update 1**
On Mac usb devices info it's shown as "1.06" (correctly):

```
$system_profiler SPUSBDataType
USB:

    USB 3.0 Bus:

      Host Controller Driver: AppleUSBXHCISPTLP
      PCI Device ID: 0x9d2f 
      PCI Revision ID: 0x0021 
      PCI Vendor ID: 0x8086 

        Vendor-Specific Device:

          Product ID: 0x0753
          Vendor ID: 0x16d0
          Version: 1.06
          Speed: Up to 1.5 Mb/sec
          Location ID: 0x14400000 / 19
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: it would be great to find according source code to know for sure as android is open source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no high level Android API to return the USB `bcdDevice` value.

The value of `UsbDevice.getVersion()` is actually the value of `bcdUSB` meaning it's the USB device specification version.

There are two ways (that I know) to get `bcdDevice` on Android:

- as pointed out by ddATC -> use `UsbDeviceConnection.getRawDescriptors()` the values of `bcdDevice` are bytes 12 and 13.
- manually execute `controlTransfer` action to read the device descriptor: example code: https://github.com/androidthings/sample-usbenum

More USB spec info:

- http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_4.htm (contains detailed information on the parameters that `controlTransfer` can accept)
- https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/viewchm.php/hs/usb.chm/usb5.htm#DeviceDescriptors (the response of the `GET_DESCRIPTOR - 0x06` command)

p.s.
I'm personally using `UsbDeviceConnection.getRawDescriptors()` to read the `bcdDevice` value.

Comment: It's bytes at index 12 and 13, with zero-based indexing. 12 is the low byte and 13 is the high byte, so `{0x01, 0x02}` = `0x0201`.

Answer (score 2):

That function is not intended to return bcdDevice. It creates a unique ID that is based on the usb file system. If you try getDeviceName() and compare to getDeviceId() you will see the device ID is a combination of the last 2 path entries from getDeviceName().

```
11-27 19:56:31.380 24948-24948/com.cirrus.cirruslogic D/com.cirrus.cirruslogic.MainActivity: getDeviceName: /dev/bus/usb/001/002
11-27 19:56:31.380 24948-24948/com.cirrus.cirruslogic D/com.cirrus.cirruslogic.MainActivity: getDeviceId: 1002
```

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html#getDeviceId() -

getDeviceId "Returns a unique integer ID for the device. This is a convenience for clients that want to use an integer to represent the device, rather than the device name. IDs are not persistent across USB disconnects."

I am trying to read bcdDevice too. Still haven't found a solution

-- UPDATE --
It appears getRawDescriptors() https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#getRawDescriptors() will do what you need. 
"Returns the raw USB descriptors for the device. This can be used to access descriptors not supported directly via the higher level APIs." Bytes 12-13 should be bcdDevice

Comment: this is strange one have to create connection to device just to get some of its attributes. How did you figure it's 12-13 bytes? Any source code proof for that?